# How to find a slider image in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
<div id="bannerBg">
    <div id="containingDiv">
        <div id="banner-fade">
            <ul class="bjqs">
                <li>
                    <img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/8962835311407882364.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/15717527901407876556.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/5158579491407874706.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/20067615141407882364.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/17148640751407882364.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/16658741621407876556.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find this code in `code igniter`. I am new to `code igniter` and I have no idea how to start, moreover most of the codes don't run in the browser because no direct access is allowed. Someone please help me with this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, in no uncertain terms?

Answer (score 1):

First make a file and save it in controller folder with any name like say image.php(if you using CI 3.X it should be Image.php otherwise it wouldn't work.). Then set it as default controller in the routes.php file(you can find it in config folder). code for controller file should be like this:

```
<?php
//if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Image extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->view('image'); // name of your html file whose code you have written above.
    }
}
?>
```

And change this `http://yousounds.com/admin/img/gallery/original/17148640751407882364.jpg`
into

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/gallery/original/17148640751407882364.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want image path in CI, Use

```
src="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/img/gallery/original/8962835311407882364.jpg"
```

so your final code will be

```
<img alt="bannerimage" class="slider-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/img/gallery/original/8962835311407882364.jpg">
```

then file structure will be (according to your `src`)

```
- admin
 - img
  - gallery
    - original
      - 8962835311407882364.jpg
```

**Note:** To use `base_url()` do this configurations in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```